# How to capture minus sign in scientific notation with regex?

Tags: regex, r, scientific-notation

I was trying to answer a question (that later got deleted) that I think was asking about extracting text representations of scientific notation. (Using R's implementation of regex that requires double escapes for meta-characters and can be used in either pure PCRE or Perl modes, the difference between which I don't really understand.)  I've solved most of the task but still seem to be failing to capture the leading minus-sign within a capture group. The only way I seem to get it to succeed is by using the leading open-parenthesis:

```
> txt <- c("this is some random text (2.22222222e-200)", "other random (3.33333e4)", "yet a third(-1.33333e-40)", 'and a fourth w/o the "e" (2.22222222-200)')
> sub("^(.+\\()([-+]{0,1}[0-9][.][0-9]{1,16}[eE]*[-+]*[0-9]{0,3})(.+$)", "\\2" ,txt)
[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "-1.33333e-40"    "2.22222222-200" 

> sub("^(.+\\()([-+]?[0-9][.][0-9]{1,16}[eE]*[-+]*[0-9]{0,3})(.+$)", "\\2" ,txt)
[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "-1.33333e-40"    "2.22222222-200" 
 #but that seems to be "cheating" ... my failures follow:

> sub("^(.+)([-+]?[0-9][.][0-9]{1,16}[eE]*[-+]*[0-9]{0,3})(.+$)", "\\2" ,txt)
[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "1.33333e-40"     "2.22222222-200" 
> sub("^(.+)(-?[0-9][.][0-9]{1,16}[eE]*[-+]*[0-9]{0,3})(.+$)", "\\2" ,txt)
[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "1.33333e-40"     "2.22222222-200" 
> sub("^(.+)(-*[0-9][.][0-9]{1,16}[eE]*[-+]*[0-9]{0,3})(.+$)", "\\2" ,txt)
[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "1.33333e-40"     "2.22222222-200"
```

I've searched SO to the extent of my patience with terms like `scientific notation regex minus'

Comment: Can you update to your question to clearly show the starting input and desired output?

Comment: The question creates the input character vector as input using R code, and I posted two correct answers that relied on the method I called "cheating". I'm don't know how it could be any more reproductible

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  In the last three `"1.33333e-40"` is different

Comment: Thanks...I got it now ^ ^

Comment: With `str_extract_all` it seems to work `unlist(str_extract_all(txt, '-?[0-9.]+e?[-+]?[0-9]*'))`

Comment: Post as an answer and I'll accept.  It, of course, would accept `numbers` like "161.1.60.40" but that seems acceptable.

Comment: one could perhaps compare the extracted digits to their `abs()` alter-ego, and isolate negatives based on that comparison.

Comment: first result when googling "regex capture real number" - http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @eddi That might have been a useful starting point, but certainly not a full R answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
 library(stringr)
 unlist(str_extract_all(txt, '-?[0-9.]+e?[-+]?[0-9]*'))
 #[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "-1.33333e-40"    "2.22222222-200"
```

Using method based on capturing after leading parentheses

```
 str_extract(txt, '(?<=\\()[^)]*')
 #[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "-1.33333e-40"    "2.22222222-200"
```

Comment: I think `stringr` now uses the code in some other package, but I don't see mention of that in the package NEWS.

Comment: @BondedDust It seems so, I am getting the message that `perl is deprecated. Please use regexp instead`.

Comment: @BondedDust According to  https://github.com/hadley/stringr  Is built on top of stringi which uses the ICU library to provide fast, correct implementations of common string manipulations

Comment: That's ithe package But I see no mention of that in my installed version. Maybe this is just in the Github version?  (Tried to compile on Mac and it errored out `configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check` ....  so I'm still on the CRAN version.)

Comment: @BondedDust I am not sure about that

Answer (score 2):

Reasoning that it was the "greedy" capacity of the "(.+)" first capture group to gobble up the minus sign that was optional in the second capture-group, I terminated the first capture-group with a negation-character-class and now have success. This still seems clunky and hoping there is something more elegant. In searching have seen Python code that seems to imply that there are regex definitions of "&real_number">

```
> sub("^(.+[^-+])([-+]?[0-9][.][0-9]{1,16}[eE]*[-+]*[0-9]{0,3})(.+$)", "\\2" ,txt,perl=TRUE)
[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "-1.33333e-40"    "2.22222222-200"
```

After looking at the code in str_extract_all which uses substr to extract matches, I now think I should have chosen the gregexpr-regmatches paradigm for my efforts rather than the pick-the-middle of-a-three-capture-group strategy:

```
> hits <- gregexpr('[-+]?[0-9][.][0-9]{1,16}[eE]*[-+]*[0-9]{0,3}', txt)
> ?regmatches
> regmatches(txt, hits)
[[1]]
[1] "2.22222222e-200"

[[2]]
[1] "3.33333e4"

[[3]]
[1] "-1.33333e-40"

[[4]]
[1] "2.22222222-200"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, and won't match an IP address:

```
sub("^.*?([-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)*(?:[Ee]?[-+]?\\d+)?).*?$", "\\1", txt)
[1] "2.22222222e-200" "3.33333e4"       "-1.33333e-40"    "2.22222222-200"
```

Oddly, that's not quite the regex I started with. When try one didn't work, I thought I would go back and test in Perl:

```
my @txt = (
  "this is some random text (2.22222222e-200)",
  "other random (3.33333e4)",
  "yet a third(-1.33333e-40)" ,
  'and a fourth w/o the "e" (2.22222222-200)');

map { s/^.*?[^-+]([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d*)*(?:[Ee]?[-+]?\d+)?).*?$/$1/ } @txt;

print join("\n", @txt),"\n";
```

And that looked good:

```
2.22222222e-200
3.33333e4
-1.33333e-40
2.22222222-200
```

So the same regex should work in R, right?

```
sub("^.*?[^-+]([-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)*(?:[Ee]?[-+]?\\d+)?).*?$", "\\1", txt)
[1] "0" "4" "0" "0"
```

Apparently not. I even confirmed that the double-quoted string is correct by trying it in Javascript with `new RegExp("`...`")`, and it worked fine there, too.  Not sure what's different about R, but removing the negated sign character class did the trick.

Comment: R uses the  version of TRE library of Ville Laurikari (http://laurikari.net/tre/) for the non-Perl regex.